# what does "blog & tweet" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> He’s making 10 sales a month. Even if I wrote pants-droppingly good copy for him and increased his sales by 200% — a % lift any CRO expert would blog & tweet about — this would only generate an extra $200 per month for his business:

Comment: In this context, [blog](http://www.onelook.com/?w=blog&ls=a) and [tweet](http://www.onelook.com/?w=tweet&ls=a) mean what the dictionaries say they mean.

Answer (score 1):

A **blog** is an online journal; searching the word on Google will give you many examples. *To blog* is to write in *a* blog.

**Twitter** is an online social networking site where people post **tweets**, short messages. Again, Google it and head to Twitter for examples. *To tweet* is to write one or more tweets.

Overall, the phrase refers to sharing something on social media - in this case, because the 200% increase is important or unusual enough to share.